# Can Selenium Grid be configured to require authentication?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

How can I force the Selenium hub/node require a password to be accessed?  I don't mean authenticate the browser.  I mean require the Selenium server to ask for a password before it will execute a test.

It seems that if you are running a Selenium hub or node you are at great risk unless you are in a very private network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the answer is no.

It is however an open source project so you could write the functionality to do this and offer up a patch.  the source is available here:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/checkout

Or if you prefer github, the github mirror is:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium

Comment: Thanks.  I can now stop looking for a solution that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @RobertL.Did you get any solution for this?