# HTTP Basic Auth in Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I want to implement `Basic Http Authentication` in `Selenium Grid` how do I do that? For eg: I want to send request to grid but not without authentication in the URL. I need to create something like this http://username:password@mygrid.com:4444/wd/hub in our internal Selenium grid. How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium Alert -- Prompt username and password is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328654/python-selenium-alert-prompt-username-and-password-is-not-working)

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question is totally different from my question. That question is about automating a site which has BASIC Auth. But this one is about implementing Basic Auth for Selenium grid.

Comment: I think the answer is no, here is the dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593670/can-selenium-grid-be-configured-to-require-authentication

Comment: Actually this looks promising for what you are looking for https://github.com/seleniumkit/gridrouter

Comment: @nilesh: I saw grid router. But I can only use stock grid and not customized grid.

Comment: You could write a simple proxy that just authenticates, if its successful route it to the grid behind else throw validation error.

Comment: @nilesh - Can you pls point me to an example?

Comment: @Damien-Amen Did you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I was able to achieve what I needed. I installed `nginx` and added the `selenium` grid endpoint to it. Then added

```
auth_basic           “Grid’s Area”;
auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
```

in the `nginx.conf`. That's it.

Please remember grid has multiple `URI` and does not have any `root` (In `nginx` terms) URI. So when you proxy let's say `/grid` to `http://localhost:4444/grid/console` all the static content cannot be served. In this case we need to proxy `/` to `http://localhost:4001`. This is because the static content is served from a different `URI`. In our case it's being served from `/grid/resources/org/openqa/grid/images/` which is different from `/grid/console`.

As far as getting `SSL` working I follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04) guide and it's super easy.

Comment: Short n sweet :) Awesome!

Comment: +1 Awesome, I was going in that direction but unnecessarily complicating things by introducing proxy, glad that its resolved.

Comment: Ok. With all that I got the redirect working fine. But the `js` and `css` and `jpg` basically `static` content is lost if I'm behind a `nginx`. `Selenium Grid` has static objects in a folder inside the `jar`. But `nginx` does not understand that path. I tried many things but couldn't get it working. Any thoughts? @KrishnanMahadevan @nilesh ?

Comment: @Damien-Amen - No I dont think there's any work around

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan: Sorry didn't update. I was able to fix the issue. In fact I was even able to setup a `load balancer` in front of the `grids`. Also got the `SSL` working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share that information on what all you did here ? That way others also will be benefitted by reading this thread.

Comment: @Damien-Amen Indeed, I was hoping to see what you did to get it working.